# Should I use directives for Simple buttons in a production quality application

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to figure out the best practices of WHEN is an appropriate situation to use a directive versus just writing out the code.

I envisioned that we could use directives to make small reusable components so that when we design screens by cutting and pasting various elements or controls from other screens (e.g., an add button) we could do basically the equivalent in the html code. However, my colleague suggests that directives should be reserved for  encapsulating complex logic or tasks.

He is worried that this is overkill and would lead to too much directives floating around and has mentioned concerns that may come up such as the isolated scopes causing difficulty with ng-if's or other ng directives that might want to act upon the button.

Can I use directives for simple control elements? Would it lead to any hurdles as the app grows bigger and/or more complex?

There are plenty of examples online of creating directives and they use simple directives but I think they're created more for didactic purposes and so would not necessarily represent code that would be used in a 'real' situation. Thus, I'm wondering what is the appropriate place to draw the line.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is quite subjective, and likely to be closed as opinion based.

Comment: Thanks Claies. I make the question more direct to hopefully address your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives are necessary when you need to abstract logic/templating out of your application. They should be self-sufficient in that they have the logic/template necessary to function. Outside of some data being passed into them, they shouldn't rely on any external components.

It's tempting to make everything a directive because it means you can extend the logic/template in one location and it'll apply everywhere. However, if you've properly established a design pattern/UI library for your team, this is unnecessary.

For example, here are two buttons with a bit of logic which are *not* directives:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()" ng-class="{disabled: addRequest.$invalid}">Submit</button>
<button class="btn" ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>
```

These have no need to be directives - they're DOM elements needing only logic that can be achieved with the current scope and `ng-*` attributes.

For every directive you have, you're adding more javascript, possibly more http requests, extra template compiling work for angular, and more loading/processing/rendering time for the browser.

There are thousands of scenarios when directives make sense and you can't list them or always identify them, but if you have a component that's re-used across your app and needs more than some basic attributes, directives work.

However, here is an example of the most basic directive we have currently:

```
.directive('clipboard', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            value: '='
        },
        template: '<span class="btn btn-dark icon-copy-to-clipboard" data-clipboard-text="{{value}}"></span>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.clipboard = new ZeroClipboard(element);
        }
    };
});
```

Anyone on my team can use this element in our app:

```
<clipboard value="data.confirmationNumber"></clipboard>
```

The directive gives us a few benefits:

- Allows me to instantiate the `ZeroClipboard` class when the directive links. That logic is now handled automatically (and correctly) for people re-using the element.
- Gives us a place to extend the logic if needed, without impacting controller scopes. No methods to copy, no scope values to worry about, etc.
- If we ever decide to change how data is copied to the clipboard (maybe it's finally natively supported cross-browser), we can change this logic once.

We also have an `autotab` directive which works as an attribute - it automatically applies logic to a field that advances focus when the field validations rules are met.

The rest of our directives are more complex - re-usable components that always appear in the app the same way. Custom field types, panels, etc.

Comment: Thank @helion3 Could you clarify what you mean by 'ng-attr logic' I tried to look up ngAttr but could not find anything in the docs.

Comment: I've updated my answer to better explain how to determine when to use directives vs direct elements